# getline, stringstream, delimiter stuff

Tags: delimiter, cin, getline, stringstream

how do I use getline to separate a string ex. "you8only8live8once"?  This solution only sets my first word to "you" and then stops at the first "8".

Also if I want to the "8" to be an arbitrary delimiter do I just put in cin >> delimiter; then change "getline(cin, phrase, '8');" to "getline(cin, phrase, delimiter);"?

```
istringstream inSS;
string phrase;
string firstWord;
string secondWord;
string thirdWord;
string fourthWord;

cout << "Please enter a digit infused string to explode:" << endl;
cout << "Please enter the digit delimiter:" << endl;

getline(cin, phrase, '8');

inSS.str(phrase);
inSS >> firstWord >> secondWord >> thirdWord >> fourthWord;


cout << "The 1st word is: " << firstWord << endl;
cout << "The 2nd word is: " << secondWord << endl;
cout << "The 3rd word is: " << thirdWord << endl;
cout << "The 4th word is: " << fourthWord << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Put the phrase into a stringstream and then use getline with a delimiter in a loop to get the pieces out. https://onlinegdb.com/z8NvUpJcS